# Having trouble understanding $$$$(dir $$$$@) in Makefile using eval

Tags: makefile

The Makefile template is as follows:

```
# cc compile template, generate rule for dep, obj: (file, cc[, flags, dir])
define cc_template

$$(call todep,$(1),$(4)): $(1) | $$$$(dir $$$$@)

    @$(2) -I$$(dir $(1)) $(3) -MM $$< -MT "$$(patsubst %.d,%.o,$$@) $$@"> $$@

$$(call toobj,$(1),$(4)): $(1) | $$$$(dir $$$$@)

    @echo + cc $$<

    $(V)$(2) -I$$(dir $(1)) $(3) -c $$< -o $$@

ALLOBJS += $$(call toobj,$(1),$(4))

endef

# compile file: (#files, cc[, flags, dir])
define do_cc_compile

$$(foreach f,$(1),$$(eval $$(call cc_template,$$(f),$(2),$(3),$(4))))

endef
```

I know eval will expand twice, so we should use another `$`. But why should we use `$$$$(dir $$$$@)` here? I have tried to understand this, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

When make parses the file, it expands.  If it sees `$$` it expands it to `$`.  So `$$$$` will expand to `$$` (two dollars).   The eval, once applied will want to expand that once more to `$`.   Thus you need four dollars (note `$$$` would expand to `$` followed by the expansion of `$(`, or whatever the next character happens to be, which would likley result in an error)